# Populate FullCalendar events as an array - populate from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am very new to JS.  My call to the web service returns an array like this:

```
data {...}
    [0]: {...}
    [1]: {...}
    [2]: {...}
    [3]: {...}
    length: 4 

    data[0] {...}
    __type: "acme.acmeSystem.EventManagement.Event"
    Amenity: {...}
    DateFrom: "/Date(1326952800000)/"
    DateTo: "/Date(1326952800000)/"
    Description: "Friends coming over for a party."
    Food: false
    Id: 3
    IsPrivate: true
    Notes: ""
    NumberOfPeople: "Less than 10"
    Status: {...}
    TimeFrom: "8:30 AM"
    TimeTo: "11:30 AM"
    User: {...}
```

How can I plug this in to the FullCalendar?

I am trying something like this:

```
GetEvents([], false,
    {
        successCallback: function (data) {
            if ((data) && (data != null) && (data.length > 0)) {

                buildingEvents = data;                  

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    theme: true,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    events: buildingEvents
                });

            }

            data = null;
        }
    });
```

I need to create another array of the FullCalendar events from the building events array:

Something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
            end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
    ]
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess you could use the jquery function [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

> **jQuery.map( array, callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray) ) Returns: Array**
>   Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Basically you will map you data received from your sever into an array of EventData objects understandable by fullCalendar:

```
var buildingEvents = $.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        id: item.Id,
        title: item.Description,
        start: ... // "bind" all properties as needed
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  That worked.  Just wanted to make a correction (colon instead of =) Hence, var buildingEvents = $.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        id: item.Id,
        title: item.Description,
        start: ... // "bind" all properties as needed
    };
});

Comment: A second reference for this type of implementation can be found here: http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/exploring-jquery-plugin-fullcalendar/ 
This question was very helpful to me. Thanks!